# php root folder $_SERVER vs dirname

Tags: php, pointers, directory, root

Anyone know if there is a "best" or industry standard for pointing/ calling a file? Lets say that there are folders and subfolders involved also. I've found some different ways to go around doing it. Just looking for some pointers ~.^ and opinions.

Windows vs Linux (even though I'm using Linux, just for others that come across this post)

```
    (dirname(__FILE__))
    BASE_PATH
    $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Comment: Pointing at WHAT file? the file this code executes in? Some other file? There is no "best" way. Each method has its ups/downs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../my/path/to/file.php';
```

That way it is always correct regardless of `$_SERVER`, OS, or include paths.